# How to make the cursor move back up 1 line

Tags: c

Example,

```
printf("1 reading");
printf("2 writing");
printf("3 drawing");
printf("What is your choice:");
scanf("%d",&choice);
```

if the users did not enter 1 or 2 or 3, the cursor to go back to:
What is your choice: using escape cope to go back to the place after the ":".

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case statement, and a while that let you repeat the *Enter value* unless 1, 2 or 3 is inserted

```
 bool repeat = true;
 //here all your printf...
 while(repeat){
     printf("Enter value: ");
     scanf("%d", &value);
     repeat = false;
     switch(value){
          case 1:
                //manage case 1
                break;
          case 2:
                //manage case 2
                break;
           case 3:
                //manage case 3
                break;
           default:
                //manage the case value inserted is different from 1, 2 and 3
                repeat = true;      
     }
 }
```

I hope it was useful.